# CSS, HTML - Site displays very wrong in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Please look at this link - http://sklepylaserowe.test.dih.pl/.
It displays well in Firefox, Chrome and Opera - but it's messed up in Internet Explorer (8 and 9). What could be a reason of it? (From list "Wybierz województwo", please select "śląskie", click "Dalej >>", and click on link that appears, to hide that overlay window)

Many basic CSS commands don't work, like:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Comment: `margin:0 auto` isn't supported by IE :(

Comment: @silentw - It isn't supported by IE 5.5 and earlier. It is supported by IE 6 and newer (but Quirks mode emulates that IE 5.5 bug).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are failing to start the document with a Doctype, this triggers [Quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) in which browsers emulate the bugs of their ancient ancestors.

Not supporting auto margins for centring is one of these bugs in IE (it was fixed in IE 6).

[Validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your HTML. You cannot put any tags before the Doctype.

Comment: @Christoph - hence "failing to start" and the final paragraph rather than "missing" :)

Comment: @Christoph Which – from the point of view of MS IE – is the same as having none…

Comment: @Quentin I misread;) You are right, I was wrong, how could a 5k User dare to correct a 165k Master. My Bad, plase forgive me o.O (:-D)

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for your answer. That seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/geo.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
```

Change above code to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/geo.js"></script>
    ...
```

Comment: That is still wrong. Script elements are not allowed outside the head/body elements.

Comment: I mentioned the order.. Edited the answer.. :)